# Can't install extension prisync/pricer over composer

Tags: magento2.3, installation, composer

Marketplace Magento doesn't let customer install by package download. They only let customer install extension over composer. But when I try to install extension composer require prisync/pricer. It show a bug like this:[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This could be because you're still using Composer 1.x.

In this case you will have to upgrade composer to 2.x. However if you're using Magento <2.4.3 version, you will have to download the module and install it in `app/code` folder.

This is because Composer 2.x is only supported by Magento >=2.4.3.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I found we can fix it by rename file auth.json.sample to auth.json then add your key to this file then you can install it over the composer

More details:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html

Hope it helps someone!